# Unable to store tensor image on local drive

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is the very first time I am trying to do any operation using tensorflow. I have a 1920*1080 image from which I want a random 512*512 patch. Once the cropping is done I cannot store the image on my local drive.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# An image of format 1920*1080
filename = tf.train.string_input_producer(["/home/rishik/Downloads/Image.jpg"])

reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename)

# use png or jpg decoder based on your files.
my_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value, channels=3)

random_patch = tf.random_crop(my_img, [512,512,3])

enc = tf.image.encode_jpeg(random_patch)
cropped_file = tf.write_file("/home/rishik/Downloads/Image_2.jpg", enc)

sess = tf.Session()
result = sess.run(cropped_file)
```

Once the program is executed, terminal shows the following message and does nothing else:

```
"2018-07-02 00:50:09.414478: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA".
```

Can someone make me understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: This is a warning, not error. Are you sure that the code doesnot work?

Comment: As I said, the terminal just keeps showing this warning and does nothing else. Atleast, waiting for 5 minute nothing happens.

Comment: Did it create a new image?, that wont be printed on terminal, check the location of Image_2.png

Comment: No it did not create any new image and kept showing the warning on the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully save images to my local drive after making some changes. Although, the warning message still shows up (I think that's some issue with my setup). Please find the solution below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

filepath = "<Some filepath>"
filename = "<Some image filename>"
tensors = []

# decode image to RGB format
image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(filepath + filename), channels=3)

# crop a random patch from the image of size 512*512
random_patch = tf.random_crop(image_decoded, [512,512,3]) 

# append the tensor to the list of rest of the tensors
tensors.append(random_patch)

# encode the random patch into JPEG format and then write the file to the local drive
enc = tf.image.encode_jpeg(random_patch)

# write the new cropped file at the directory random_patches created
image = filepath + "random_patches/" + filename
cropped_file = tf.constant(image)
fwrite = tf.write_file(cropped_file, enc) 

sess = tf.Session()
result = sess.run(fwrite)
```